# E-mail signature in MS Outlook using custom CSP

Tags: windows, cryptography

I have developed a CSP (cryptographic service provider). This CSP can access my Smart Card. My target is E-mail Signing in MS Outlook and Document Signing in MS-Word. I have test my CSP by a sample test application (Written by me). It can perform Signature operation without any error.

Now I want to E-mail signature as like Smart Card BaseCSP. Is it possible, to set my CSP as default CSP?

How to configure my CSP in registry to perform E-mail signing in MS-Outlook?

Comment: You'll probably need to make a key store containing your certificate available within your CSP. Then if the certificate (including private key according to the slightly warped way of looking at certificates that Microsoft uses) matches your mail address and is fit for signing email it can be chosen to sign the mail. Sorry, I'm not a MS developer, can't help you much further, but this is the basic operation of how the private key is found. Do you indicate a certificate for the user already?

Comment: You don't want to "set your provider as default CSP", you just want to use your smart card for specific private key operations.